# VSTO C#: Read the current Cell value which is always nul

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Scenario:

I have to read the content of the Active cell in active sheet. If the value is nonempty e.g. "abc" on that time I have to disable the one item in ribbon bar and when the user has clear the cell on that time item should be enable item in the ribbon bar.

I have written this code to get the value of current cell:

```
private string CurrrentCellValue()
{
    var BeginCell = string.Empty;
    var CellValue = string.Empty;

    var activeWorkBook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;

    if (activeWorkBook != null)
    {
        var sheet = activeWorkBook.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;
        if (!sheet.ProtectContents)
        {
            var range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection as Range;
            if (range != null)
            {
                string address = range.get_Address();
                string[] cells = address.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                BeginCell = cells[0].Replace("$", "");
                var activeSheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
                range = activeSheet.Range(BeginCell);
                Range item = range.get_Item(1);
                CellValue = item.Value2;
            }
        }
    }

    return CellValue;

}
```

Item in ribbon bar:

I have used the command(ICommand) with item in ribbon bar

```
 _ribbonItem.ItemOpenCommand = new DelegateCommand(ItemButtonClick,    canexecuteMethdod1);
```

what I have done is:

In canexecuteMethdod1 Method, I have called the method to read the current cell, if the cell value is not null on that time ItemButtonClick method won't execute otherwise it will.

But the problem I'm facing that when there is some value in the active cell I'm getting all the value as null. how can dynamically I read the content of the active cell?

in short, I'm trying to replicate the fx(insert function) of excel.

Please Help.

Comment: Are you trying to tell if Excel is in cell-edit mode, or do you only want to get the value of the active cell after it's been accepted by the user?  Cell values are accepted when the user exits  cell-edit mode by pressing enter, tab, cursor keys, etc...  If what you want is the former then there's an existing question for how to tell if Excel is in cell-edit mode.

Comment: I have used SendKeys("{ENTER}") to exit the cell in edit mode and now if I'm typing any value in cell, my ribbon item is disabled and if clear the cell ribbon item is enabled. But problem is when I'm running any formula it's giving output in form of string and when selecting the cell even on that time also item in ribbon is disabled but it should enabled please help.